# Api facebook nao retorna data de nascimento

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

Estou usando a api do facebook para fazer o login e pegar alguns dados do usuario como nome, sobrenome etc.

```
 function apilogin() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('me/','GET',{fields:'first_name,last_name,email,birthday'}, function(response) {
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    '<br>Nome: ' + response.first_name + '<br>Sobrenome: '+response.last_name + '<br>email: '+response.email+'<br>Data nascimento: '+response.birthday;
});


<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="2" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="email,public_profile,user_birthday" onlogin='checkLoginState();' auth-type="rerequest">login com o facebook</div>
```

Eu defini todas as permissoes e parametros necessários, porem ele so retorna a data quando eu logo no facebook onde criei o aplicativo, gostaria de saber se é necessario alguma configuração no aplicativo, ou se é falta de uma sintaxe especifica pelo menos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As únicas informações que a Graph API fornece sem análise é o [perfil público](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-public_profile), as demais precisam passar por uma análise pelo Facebook, e, caso aprovado, o aplicativo terá permissão de obter as demais informações requisitadas - provavelmente por esse motivo você não está conseguindo obter a data de nascimento.

> Caso seu aplicativo solicite essa permissão, o Facebook terá que
>   analisar como seu aplicativo a utiliza.
>
> Ao enviar para análise, seja claro com relação ao motivo da age_range
>   não ser suficiente para seu caso de uso.

Em cenário de teste é possível o administrador do app inserir contas do facebook (usuários), como [usuário](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users?locale=pt_BR) de teste.

[Referência](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_birthday) do birthday. Interessante notar que a maioria das integrações precisará apenas da *age_range* que acompanha a permissão *public_profile*.

Comment: Valeu cara, vou enviar essa solicitação. Realmente inseri um usuário como usuário de teste e consegui recuperar a data de nascimento